# Mongoid: how to re-order association ids in many to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm new to mongodb and mongoid and I'm trying to figure out how I would go about reordering the _ids array on a many to many relationship.

Given these two models

```
class Event
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, type: String

  has_and_belongs_to_many :performers
end

class Performer
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, type: String

  has_and_belongs_to_many :events
end
```

The data is working well but I'm curious how I would set a specific order on the performer_ids on the event document.

Is there a quick way to do this or is it just updating the full record anytime that order changes?

UPDATE: Here's how I see the document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5acfdbb13ae740cf10015d2d"),
    "name" : "Edna O'Brien",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2018-04-12T22:20:33.105Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2018-04-12T22:20:33.105Z"),
    "performer_ids" : [ 
        ObjectId("5acfda693ae740ce8c016bab"), 
        ObjectId("5acfda773ae740ce8c017959"), 
        ObjectId("5acfda703ae740ce8c017299")
    ]
}
```

I'm looking to be able to control the order of the performer_ids, for instance if I later want the ability to re order the performers for showing on the frontend.

```
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5acfdbb13ae740cf10015d2d"),
    "name" : "Edna O'Brien",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2018-04-12T22:20:33.105Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2018-04-12T22:20:33.105Z"),
    "performer_ids" : [ 
        ObjectId("5acfda703ae740ce8c017299"),
        ObjectId("5acfda773ae740ce8c017959"),
        ObjectId("5acfda693ae740ce8c016bab")

    ]
}
```

Comment: How do you plan to order the IDs? Afaik mongoid IDs are alphanumeric codes. If you want to reorder the objects instead of IDs, you can use scopes OR default scope in the associated model.

Comment: When using this habtm setup there's an attribute called (for example on events) performer_ids that just reference the pk of the performer. I want to control the order of those for display purposes

Comment: Can you give an example with actual IDs? how do you see them now? How do you want them?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh - I updated the question with the relevant data. Thanks!

Comment: You added, how it looks now. Also add, how do you want it to look?

Comment: Ok, i've added an example of how I want it to look and the use case for reordering the associated ids.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't get the logic you are using to order the IDs. They don't seem to be in ascending or descending order. What is the algorithm you are using (OR want to use) to sort them?